# Same Where Clause, different select query

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an application using ADO.NET to connect with MS SQL Server, in one of my use cases, user has the option to search and view the data or download the data, based on search criteria.

Search criteria has around 25-30 options, so where clause got complex. If user wants to view the data, I need to select 7 columns but if user wants to download than there are like around 150 columns.

From online search I have figured out that it is not possible to have different select query with same where clause and only option is the dynamic SQL.

My question is which option will be better from performance point of view, either to use the dynamic SQL and reduce number of select columns to 7 if only viewing or select 150 columns in every case without using dynamic SQL.

Most of the time users will be searching to view the data, download is less used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really vague. But do not select 150 columns all the time when you only need 7. That is pushing all that data through the pipe and throwing it away.

Comment: It's not really dynamic sql if it's built in a .net application.  Your question doesn't mention how the sql is built or executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two stored procedures, one to return the 7 columns, and one to return the 150 columns. They could accept the search criteria as parameters, and your code could determine which one to use based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

As your application grows in size, pulling all those columns(depending on their type and content) could be a less performant option than selecting just the 7 columns.